# Truncating string with re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I have a url stored as `type=str`. Looks like this:

```
url = 'http://www.dog.com/bone?junk=8dj37hf7'
```

I want to delete all chars beginning with '?', so I would have:

```
url = 'http://www.dog.com/bone'
```

This is what I've tried:

```
import re
re.sub('?junk=*', '', url)
```

But I get this error:

> > > raise error, v # invalid expression
> > >       sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

This is the solution:

```
import re
re.sub('\?junk=.*', '', url)
```

---

Edited to insert code bracketing. 
Edited to add .* notation per 
Morten Jensen, but the error persists.

Edit: Solved with '.*' and '\' escape. Thanks to Morten Jensen, jwodder, thefourtheye, et al.

Comment: Try `re.sub('?junk=.*', '', url)`. The error message implies you need a dot before the asterisk :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not just

```
url = url.split("?",1)[0]
```

regex seems like trying to kill a fly with a sledgehammer here

Comment: Indeed.  The question is a pretty good example of "now you have two problems" (http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

Comment: lol im not sure you had to cite that :P ... almost every programmer knows it :P but +1 for knowing that ... I almost put that as the answer but decided it would be counter productive

Comment: I was curious whether there are altogether better approaches. At least 3 people think so. Thanks for the link, will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

> `'?'`
>
> Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the
>   preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

So, you need to escape the `?` with a backslash

```
url = 'http://www.dog.com/bone?junk=8dj37hf7'
import re
print re.sub('\?.*', '', url)
```

**Output**

```
http://www.dog.com/bone
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `?` in a regex causes the immediately preceding item to become optional, and yet there is no preceding item here; to avoid this behavior, you need to escape the `?` with a backslash.  Similarly, `=*` will match zero or more `=`s, not one `=` followed by whatever, which would be `=.*`.  Thus, to get what you want, you need to use:

```
re.sub(r'\?junk=.*', '', url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try what thefourtheye said, or probably this:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.dog.com/bone?junk=8dj37hf7'
>>> newurl = url[:url.find('?')]
>>> print newurl

http://www.dog.com/bone
```

This method is faster as well, here's proof:

```
In [2]: url = 'http://www.dog.com/bone?junk=8dj37hf7'

In [3]: %timeit newurl = url[:url.find('?')]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 423 ns per loop

In [4]: import re

In [5]: %timeit x = re.sub('\?.*', '', url)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.1 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit x = re.sub('\?.*', '', url)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.25 us per loop
```

Comment: Note that, if `url` doesn't contain a `?`, this will result in `newurl` containing all but the last character of `url`.

Comment: yes @jwodder but it is up to the discretion of the user to use this procedural truncation method when he/she wants. So this is the best method to use when the person knows that the url has a `?`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse url, [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) is better method.

```
from urlparse import urlparse

url = 'http://www.dog.com/bone?junk=8dj37hf7'
parsed = urlparse(url)
real_url = "http://{0}{1}".format(parsed.hostname, parsed.path)
```

Output:

```
'http://www.dog.com/bone'
```

Comment: why make a mountain of a molehill?

Comment: Because maybe need to get others information such like all parameters.

Comment: this user just needs truncation